# Why SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returning null value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to build authentication in spring-cloud-gateway using keycloak authentication and everything is working but when trying to get SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() it is giving null I am not sure why?

Here it the my code Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        // Authenticate through configured OpenID Provider
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/app/**").authenticated().and().oauth2Login();

        // Also logout at the OpenID Connect provider
        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)));

        // Require authentication for all requests
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated();

        // Allow showing /home within a frame
        http.headers().frameOptions().mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.SAMEORIGIN);

        // Disable CSRF in the gateway to prevent conflicts with proxied service CSRF
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

And my controller in which I am trying to get data is as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @PostMapping(path = "/authenticate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getAuth(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data) {
     Authentication authentication =
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
     //But it is always null
    }

}
```

I gone few stackoverflow answer but it is not working according to that there is some issue with SecurityConfig class but I am not able to get it. Please help on it.

Answer (score 2):

In reactive applications, `SecurityContext` is contained in [`ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/authorization/method.html) which should be used to get `Authentication` in a reactive way as shown below:

```java
Mono<Authentication> getAuthentication() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("ReactiveSecurityContext is empty!")))
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it is also giving null. :(

Comment: If you open the referenced link, you can find an important note: "For this to work the return type of the method must be a org.reactivestreams.Publisher (i.e. Mono/Flux) or the function must be a Kotlin coroutine function. This is necessary to integrate with Reactor’s Context.". Can you try to set return type of controller method to `Mono<String>` for example?